# Add page to active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

We are wanting to add a help page to our admin and we are using the active admin gem.  This page is not associated to any model so I am struggling trying to figure out how to get the link to show up in the menu bar on every page.

Comment: Why not add a sidebar as explained here - http://activeadmin.info/docs/7-sidebars.html

Comment: Why not add a sidebar to your model like the following: `sidehar :help do render "help" end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Warning: this is hopelessly outdated, and not relevant in 2020 anymore. This was for activeadmin <0.7 versions.**

Make a file /app/models/help.rb with this contents, for more advanced tableless models you might want to check out http://keithmcdonnell.net/activerecord_tableless_model_gem.html or google your own insight together.

```
class Help < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.columns 
    @columns ||= []
  end

  # ...  

end
```

add an entry to /config/initializers/inflections.rb

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.uncountable %w( help )
end
```

set up a route for your viewlogger, in config/routes.rb:

```
match '/admin/help' => 'admin/help#index', :as => :admin_help
```

now you can formulate the activeadmin register block as follows (make you sure you create a view partial in the right place)

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register Help do      
  config.comments = false
  before_filter do @skip_sidebar = true end
  # menu false
  config.clear_action_items!   # this will prevent the 'new button' showing up    
  controller do
    def index
      # some hopefully useful code
      render 'admin/help/index', :layout => 'active_admin'
    end
  end   

end
```

Answer (score 17):

I know I'm a little late, but I usually am :D.

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Help" do

  content do
    panel "My Panel Test" do
      "Hello World"
    end
  end  


  sidebar "Test Sidebar" do
    "Hi World"
  end
end
```

Here's the corresponding code block in active_admin

```
# Register a page
#
# @param name [String] The page name
# @options [Hash] Accepts option :namespace.
# @&block The registration block.
#
def register_page(name, options = {}, &block)
  namespace_name = extract_namespace_name(options)
  namespace = find_or_create_namespace(namespace_name)
  namespace.register_page(name, options, &block)
end
```

Comment: It's also in the Active Admin documentation: http://activeadmin.info/docs/9-custom-pages.html Note that you need a fairly recent version of Active Admin for this to work: I had to upgrade from 0.3.4 to 0.4.3

Comment: Where should the code in the first snippet (with the register_page method) be put?