# ActiveAdmin how to add a custom controller without model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add page to active admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639978/add-page-to-active-admin)

I currently looking to a solution for adding a controller without a model to the admin generate by ActiveAdmin (and Rails 3.1).
Of course I'd like to add a new menu in the navbar.

Using `ActiveAdmin.register MyControllerWithoutModel do` isn't working.

Edit : This question is a duplicate of [Add page to active admin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7639978/836604) but no answer found.

Comment: A solution is to create a dummy model but after do that, I have this error : "undefined method `quoted_table_name' for MyControllerWithoutModel:Class"

Comment: Do **not** post a question again just because an answer wasn't found.  If you have details about the question, you can suggest an edit.  Additionally, if you gain some more reputation, you can offer a bounty on the question which will garner it more views and possibly more answers.  Duplicating a question intentionally may lead to flags on your posts which may lead to further moderator action.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me, just substitute the right name for *ViewLogger* in the codeblocks. This way you wont have to create a dummy table in your database.

Make a file /app/models/viewlogger.rb with this contents, for more advanced tableless models you might want to check out http://keithmcdonnell.net/activerecord_tableless_model_gem.html or google your own insight together.

```
class Viewlogger < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.columns 
    @columns ||= []
  end

  # ...  

end
```

add an entry to /config/initializers/inflections.rb

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.uncountable %w( viewlogger )
end
```

set up a route for your viewlogger, in config/routes.rb:

```
match '/admin/viewlogger' => 'admin/viewlogger#index', :as => :admin_viewlogger
```

now you can formulate the activeadmin register block as follows (make you sure you create a view partial in the right place)

```
ActiveAdmin.register Viewlogger do
  config.comments = false
  before_filter do @skip_sidebar = true end
  # menu false
  config.clear_action_items!   # this will prevent the 'new button' showing up


  controller do
    def index
      # some hopefully useful code
      render 'admin/viewlogger/index', :layout => 'active_admin'
    end
  end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this to edit application configuration, but it seams that without model it is impossible. I just created empty model with table in db and register the resource as usual.

To customize resource:

disable filters

```
config.clear_sidebar_sections!
```

custom menu path

```
ActiveAdmin.application.namespaces[:admin].resources['Configuration'].namespace.menu.items.each{|i| i.instance_eval('@cached_url[:admin_configurations_path] = "/admin"')}
```