# rails 3.2 Getting route error with active admin 0.5.5 member_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin

I have successfully merged devise, active admin and cancan using a single User model for authorization and authentication on both admin and front end of my web application, i have Boolean flag for user model approved? so they can publish their applications  (which true or false of approved state in database).
now i want to "only" approve a user through the admin page.

```
in app\model\user.rb

def approve!
  #set approved boolean state in database to true
  approved = true
end

def disapprove!
  #set approved boolean state in database to false
  approved = false
end
```

in active admin i have.

```
app\admin\user.rb

  member_action :approve, :method => :put do
    App.find(params[:id]).approve!
    redirect_to [:admin, resource], :notice => "Developer Approved"
  end

   member_action :disapprove, :method => :put do
      user = User.find(params[:id])
      user.disapproved!
      redirect_to admin_user_path(user), notice: "Successfully Disapproved Developer!"
   end
```

and this for column links

```
    column "Approve Developer" do |user|

       if user.developer? && user.approved_developer?
       link_to 'Disapprove Developer', "#"

    elsif user.developer? && !user.approved_developer?
       link_to 'Approve Developer',approve_admin_user_path

    else
       "Not A Developer"
    end

  end
```

running rake routes show me

```
approve_admin_user PUT    /admin/users/:id/approve(.:format)  admin/users#approve
disapprove_admin_user PUT    /admin/users/:id/approve(.:format)  admin/users#disapprove
```

everything seems fine but when i load page and click on with approve developer link or disapprove developer link i get `No route matches {:action=>"approve", :controller=>"admin/users"}` error.

i have also set up route for active admin as `ActiveAdmin.routes(self)` in routes.rb
i also have a `resources :users`  i still don't know what i am doing wrong over here
Help would be very much appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
map.namespace :admin do |a|
   a.resources :users, :member => {:approve => :get} 
end
```

Comment: Thank you Dipak but that didn't work either as i already have `resources :users` in routes.rb, pls check my new edits for route for active admin.

Comment: see this link ** http://activeadmin.info/docs/1-general-configuration.html#namespaces ** may be it helps you

Comment: also see this link ** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706122/activeadmin-how-to-add-a-custom-controller-without-model **

Answer (score 0):

As it can be seen in the routes entry, the :id is missing in the link creation. Try this:

```
link_to 'Approve Developer', approve_admin_user_path(:id => user.id)
```

Don't forget to restart the server if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, i think you may solve your editing this part of the code from:

```
 link_to 'Approve Developer',approve_admin_user_path()
```

to:

```
link_to 'Approve Developer',approve_admin_user_path(user), :method => :put
```

The link_to default http verb is GET, in my case it did the job.